# create OAuth 2.0 Access Token for a REST API when users signup using social auth

Tags: django, api, rest, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

am try to create access token for my Rest api  ,i used https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.2/tutorial/rest_framework_integration.html#step-4-get-your-token-and-use-your-api for oauht2 for generate access token for the Api development tool i used  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/.

if i have client_id,client_secret,username and password then ,i get Acess Token using http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/

but if sign up done using social then, i don't have password .

so any safe and secure way to generate Access token Parametrically for My Rest Api. plz Help

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 assumes your web application never gets the user's password. Nevertheless, the user is redirected to the authentication service, where he logs in with his password, and your web application gets back the authentication token.

For example, for Google authentication, the user is redirected to Google login page only for the first time. When the user confirms that the given web app can use his personal information, an authentication token is issued to that web app, which can be used from now on without asking for the password.

More information about Google OAuth2 library for Python:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

An example application with using Django:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/SampleApps#Django_Samples
Starting from this example, I was able to use Google OAuth2, get the authentication and refresh tokens, which were used to access Google APIs.

Comment: Thanks for replay, so how can get Access token and refresh token on the bases of client_id and client_ secret .

Comment: You create OAuth2WebServerFlow object from the user name and client secret. The "flow" object is used to get the redirection URL, and then to get the authentication code. It is described in the first link for Google OAuth2 for Python.